# Download Google Drive Folders from Chrome packaged app/extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I was wondering if I could download the folders from Google Drive using my Chrome packaged app? So my Chrome packaged app is integrated with Google Drive. When I click on "download files" it takes me to the Google Drive page where I can see all the folders but whenever I click on folder it opens up and goes to the files. I just want to download the whole folder to my web app.